# Eclipse buttons like Step in, Step out, resume etc.. not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I am debugging my code but the Debug tools are not clickable (i.e Step in , Step out , resume etc).I might have changed the settings accidently , but I dont know where to reset it .

I am new to use Eclipse and android , Please help me

[image: Debug Buttons]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In the "Debug" perspective, there is a "Debug" view which shows the threads of the application being debugged:
[image: Eclipse Debug view in Debug perspective]

There's a little menu in the top right corner, with an option "Show Debug Toolbar". Select that, et voilá:

[image: Eclipse Debug view in Debug perspective with Debug Toolbar visible]

Comment: So obvious yet so hidden.  Cheers :)

Comment: How to put that buttons on the eclipse main toolbar?

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes it helps to clean  the eclipse workspace - just start eclipse with -clean and the debug buttons work again.

Comment: This worked for me, but i had to start again without `-clean` for the controls to be enabled again.

Comment: this also worked for me, though my problem was a bit different -- My debug controls completely disappeared both from toolbar and "Run" menu, I believe it may have been connecting to installing the PyDev plugin.  After restarting with -clean, they're back.

Comment: My problem was permemently disappearing debug buttons after making them visible and restarting IDE. it seems this solution worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Window -> open perspective -> Debug. There you go.

Also it will normally open by itself when you run the project in debug mode. You do that by clicking F11 or clicking on the bug/insect icon to the left of the run (play) button in the navigation bar you provided screenshot off.

Comment: also, you need to be in the correct thread in order to keep debugging

Comment: I'm on Luna and it gets stuck at the 1st break point, Resume is grayed out, restarting eclipse makes no difference. This has been worknig since I upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the watch expressions takes too long to evaluate, those mentioned buttons will appear to be grayed out during the evaluation. In such case removing all watch expressions will help.

Answer (score 0):

You may see that your breakpoints symbols are double lines instead of dots.

Click:

> Run > Skip All Breakpoints

After this you will see that the breakpoints icons are back to normal and your problem is resolved.